# How to check if a dimension is applied to a parameter in the Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api

Is there a way to use the Revit API to see if a dimension is used in a family parameter?

Of the APIs, I have looked into the FamilyManager and FamilyParameter classes. I am also looking into the Dimension class that handles dimensions, but so far I have not found a solution.

※The environment is Revit2021 (API).

Answer (score 1):

The Building Coder topic group on the [Family API for Creating Family Definitions](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.25.1) and the [Family API Labs: Creating an Example Family](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/08/the-revit-family-api.html#4)
 explain and demonstrate how a family definition can be created, including the use of `AddParameter`, `NewDimension` and `AssociateElementParameterToFamilyParameter` to achieve the association you are looking for.